# How to install and use Arango-CMS demo app?

Tags: javascript, arangodb

Arango-CMS demo app is [found here](https://devhub.io/repos/arangodb-foxx-demo-cms).

> This is a Content Management System for the ArangoDB. It is based on struct information.

What is "struct information"?

How do I perform these two installation steps?

> 1. Add a Collection you would like to manage.
> 2. Add struct information for this collection.

Can the collection be added via the WebUI, for example? Can it be any collection?

How do I add struct information for this collection?

Also, will Arango-CMS demo app work with ArangoDB v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to [refer to Foxx repository](https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/demo-cms/blob/master/repositories/structures.js), held by a variable called `structs`. The implementation [appears to be incomplete](https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/demo-cms/blob/master/cms.js) however (the `_structures` collection is never used and such a system collection does not even exist in ArangoDB 3.x).

It was written for Foxx 2.x, so it would run in legacy mode only in ArangoDB 3.x, but this demo is [not functional](https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/demo-cms/issues/1) anyway and the development was abandoned (last code change in 2013).

Instead, have a look at [Foxx 3.x](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Foxx/), which comes with much more features out of the box like support for schema validation via joi and is easier to learn compared to the old Foxx with unnecessary abstractions over collections etc.

Comment: Update: It was decided to remove the CMS demo repository to avoid further confusion.